# What the difference between Angular [checked] attribute and formControl setValue?

Tags: angular

Why if i update component property, that assigned to [checked] input, in method that called after checkbox changed the value of checkbox doesn't change.

But if i assign Form Control to same checkbox and call setValue checked status of that checkbox will change?

live code example
https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-robinson-mzpx9?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

app.component.html

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  [checked]="haveValue"
  (change)="valueChanged($event.target)"
  [formControl]="checkboxControl"
/>

<dialog #modal>
  <form method="dialog">
    <button value="default">Ok</button>
    <button (click)="cancel()" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</dialog>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  haveValue = true;
  @ViewChild("modal") modal: ElementRef<HTMLDialogElement>;

  checkboxControl = new FormControl(true);

  valueChanged(target: EventTarget): void {
    const checked = (target as HTMLInputElement).checked;
    if (!checked) {
      this.modal.nativeElement.showModal();
    }
  }

  cancel(): void {
    // if replace with 'this.haveValue = true' checked satus will not changed
    this.checkboxControl.setValue(true);
    //this.haveValue = true;
    console.log("cancel called");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Alexander, please provide some code examples, so we can help you resolve the problem

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan sorry, i provided code example

Answer (score 0):

Angular bindings react on **changes**. so `this.haveValue = true;` should change haveValue from `false` to `true` for checkbox to react.
so correct code would look like

```
valueChanged(target: EventTarget): void {
    const checked = (target as HTMLInputElement).checked;
    this.haveValue = checked; // here it is changed to false
    if (!checked) {
      this.modal.nativeElement.showModal();
    }
  }


 cancel(): void {
    this.haveValue = true; // back to true
 }
```